# Q- a resolved promise not calling the next task, Safari 6.1 + and 7+

Tags: javascript, safari, q

We have a class as part of a large framework, and we use Q as our promise library.

We have a function similar to what you see below.
this._getData() returns a promise, and all of the other functions in the 'thens' receive and return a value properly.

Everything works **most of the time.**

Sometimes in Safari 6.1 + and 7+ (mainly when the data is not yet in the cache, i.e. the first time anyone ever requests it), the first promise (this._getData()) is created **and fulfilled** (I created a local log to ensure this), but none of the 'thens' are called. Q does not pass the fulfillment value to the next task.

There was a bug that looked similar to it in Q v0.8 which was fixed in v0.9, but we upgraded to v0.9 and it has not resolved the issue.

Here's the code:

```
someAsyncFunc: function(){
    var promise =  this._getData()
                    .then(this._doSomething_1)
                    .then(this._doSomething_2)
                    .then(...)
                    .then(...)
                    .then(this._doSomething_n)
                    .fail(this._onFail);

                return promise;
}
```

It's interesting to note that once the bug happens, Q is completely broken. It may have been broken before this request due to something else that failed which uses Q, but we don't see any exceptions.

By completely broken, I mean that normally on any page which has Q (and when the bug does not occur), if you type this into the console:

```
Q(1).then(function(){console.log('then has occurred');});
```

then you will see the console log.

However, when the bug occurs, this does not happen.

Even trying:

```
var promise = Q(1);
promise.then(function(){console.log('then has occurred');});
//nothing happens
promise.isFulfilled() //true
```

Which seems to show that Q is just stuck in some weird state where it believes it is flushing when it's really not, so it never goes to the next task.

This is actually exactly what we're experiencing, as the this._getData() creates a new promise, performs an ajax call to the server and passes the deferred object to resolve into the callbacks, and successfully resolves the promise - but none of the next functions are called.

Would love to know if anyone encountered this and knows how to fix it, or has an idea how to continue debugging this.

Thanks

**Update:** After further debugging, it definitely looks like Q gets stuck flushing on a task, and is therefore never able to move to the next task.

Comment: It is possible that the event queue is stalling if an error passes through it, but we have code in place for that. I would consider tracing the size of the queue at the beginning of each event to ascertain whether this is the case.

Comment: Are your `this._*` properties functions or methods? Q does not implicitly bind handlers, so `this` would be global or undefined.

Comment: Also, what browser or Node.js version is this occurring in?

Comment: **Edit: I now notice Safari versions in the title. Thanks for your specificity.**

Comment: Cross posting to ASAP issue tracker https://github.com/kriskowal/asap/issues/34

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fits better in the issue tracker of the Q library instead of a Q&A site like StackOverflow.

Comment: the functions are all bound explicitly when the class is created.